# Execute a custom action before Product condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Basically I need to verify that a certain program is not running before installation. This is done via a custom action, which sets a property, `APPRUNNING`:

```
<CustomAction Id="CheckingAppIsRunning"
          BinaryKey="AppIsRunning"
          DllEntry="AppIsRunning"/>

<Binary Id="AppIsRunning" 
        SourceFile="CustomActions.CA.dll" />
```

But in the message displayed, `APPRUNNING` seems to be null, that is, it's not set at all (should be either "0" or "1").

```
<Condition Message="Exit all instances of [APPNAME] before installation (APPRUNNING = [APPRUNNING]).">
    <![CDATA[APPRUNNING = "0"]]>
</Condition>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CheckingAppIsRunning" Before="LaunchConditions" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I suppose the custom action is not executed at the moment of the condition check. What are the options to perform a condition check after a custom action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [LaunchConditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369751.aspx) action is scheduled to run in both `InstallUISequence` and `InstallExecuteSequence`. As long as you schedule your custom action to `InstallExecuteSequence` only, the property won't be set by the time LaunchConditions is fired in `InstallUISequence`.

You should schedule your `CheckingAppIsRunning` custom action in both sequences. You might also want to define it with `Execute='firstSequence'` attribute - this way it will run the first sequence it is met in.

This is what I mean, actually:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="CheckingAppIsRunning" Before="LaunchConditions" />
</InstallUISequence>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CheckingAppIsRunning" Before="LaunchConditions" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And the definition:

```
<CustomAction Id="CheckingAppIsRunning" BinaryKey="AppIsRunning" DllEntry="AppIsRunning" Execute="firstSequence"/>
```